# inconsistant photo url using paperclip when query in two apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am using paperclip to upload photos in my two rails app which share a single database. Now the problem is, if I upload a photo in app-a, for instance, paperclip gives me a url as:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/testing-item-photos-akiajbfjoiwfjzd6aypa/Users/yujunwu/**app-a**/public/item_19/created_at_2012-09-29%2021:52:02%20UTC/large.jpg?1348955522

Here is what I set up in my item model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :photo, :photo_url, :poll_id, :brand, :number_of_votes

    has_attached_file :photo,
                    :styles => { :thumbnail => "100x100#",
                                   :small => "150x150>",
                                   :medium => "250x250>",
                                   :large => "400x400>" },
                    :storage => :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => S3_CREDENTIALS,
                    :url=>"/item_:id/created_at_:created_at/:style.jpg"

  Paperclip.interpolates :created_at do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.created_at
  end


end
```

In the other app app-b, when I query the url with item.photo.url(:large), it gave me:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/testing-item-photos-akiajbfjoiwfjzd6aypa/Users/yujunwu/**app-b**/public/item_19/created_at_2012-09-29%2021:52:02%20UTC/large.jpg?1348955522

Therefore I got a wrong url.

Are there any ways I can do that by configuring paperclip? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described here : https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#defaults , you can change the default config, in your case I guess you want to change the `:local_root` so it doesn't include the app name.